# Ordenar listas ligadas(LinkedList) en c?

Tags: c, ordenamiento

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en C, pero me he atorado al momento de querer ordenar los Nodos. 
Tengo métodos para llenar y eliminar los nodos, el problema llega que al tratar de ordenar no hace nada, lo deja tal cual esta.
Al ingresar un usuario le asigno su nombre y su cuenta.
Los demás métodos si son correctos, al ingresar usuarios "primero" se queda apuntando al primer nodo y ultimo, al ultimo ingresado.

```
typedef  struct nodo {
    char nombre[60];
    int cuenta;
    struct nodo *siguiente; 
} nodo;
nodo*primero=NULL;
nodo*ultimo=NULL;
int i=0;

void organiza(){
    nodo*actual=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    nodo*aux=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    nodo*pivote=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));

    actual=primero;
    pivote = primero;

    if(primero!=NULL){
        while(actual!=NULL){
            aux=actual->siguiente;
            while(aux!=NULL){
                if(actual->cuenta > aux->cuenta){
                    pivote = aux;
                    aux = actual;
                    actual->cuenta = pivote;
                }
            }
            aux=aux->siguiente;
        }
        actual=actual->siguiente; 
    } else {
        printf("Vacia\n");
    }
}
```

Creo que el problema esta dentro del segundo if. Pero no estoy seguro que. 
Ya hice

```
if(actual->cuenta> aux->cuenta){
        pivote = aux->cuenta;
        aux->cuenta = actual->cuenta;
        actual->cuenta = pivote;
}
```

Y si funciona, pero no funciona cuando lo hago con `nodo->nombres`,incluso creando un pivote para los nombres. Lo que quiere decir que solo ordena las cuentas pero los nombre quedan igual.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero: haces cosas *no recomendables*:

```
nodo*actual=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
...
nodo*pivote=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
```

para, acto seguido, hacer

```
actual = primero;
pivote = primero;
```

Eso es una evidente *fuga de memoria*; asignas un bloque, pero **nunca podrás liberarlo**; si tu programa estuviera en ejecución continua mucho tiempo, terminarías por **quedarte sin memoria**, aunque en realidad no la estarías usando.

En lo referente a ordenar *por nombre*: ¿ como los comparas ? las cadenas en C **no** se pueden comparar como si fueran un tipo; piensa que una cadena no es mas que un puntero a un bloque de *bytes*, el último de los cuales es un `0`.

Para comparar cadenas, has de usar la función

```
int strcmp( const char *str1, const char *str2 );
```

Dicha función devuelve:

```
str1 < str2  -> -1
str1 == str2 ->  0
str1 > str2  ->  1
```

Bien, ahora, un *cambio* en el punto de vista. En lugar de colocar elementos en la lista, y *ordenarlos* al final, lo haremos **según los vamos insertando**. La *complejidad* del código, al hacerlo así, disminuye *drásticamente*:

```
void addToList( nodo *nuevo ) {
  // Caso trivial. Lista vacía.
  if( !primero ) {
    primero = nuevo;
    ultimo = nuevo;
    nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
  } else {
    nodo *idx = primero;

    while( idx->siguiente && ( strcmp( idx->nombre, nuevo->nombre ) < 1 ) )
      idx = idx->siguiente;

    // Al llegar aquí, idx 'apunta' al elemento tras el que tenemos que insertar.
    nuevo->siguiente = idx->siguiente;
    idx->siguiente = nuevo;
  }
}
```

**No lo he probado**, pero, salvo cambios mínimos, debería de funcionar.

Comment: Gracias por responder. 
Solo tengo una duda , ¿Por que no es recomendable hacer lo que hice?(usar nodo*actual=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));  ).
Y se supone que quiero comparar enteros(cuenta), pero mi nodo tiene dos datos: el nombre y la cuenta. Pero cuando ordeno la cuenta el nombre asociado a la cuenta no cambia de lugar. Solo se ordena la cuenta. Lo que hace que las cuentas queden con otros nombres.
Por especificación, debo de tener una opción de ordenar los nodos (usuarios) y no ordenarlos como vayan entrando. Por lo que es necesario tener una función para ordenar.

Comment: Te lo explico en la respuesta: *coges* trozos de memoria, pero *nunca* podrás liberarla; para liberar memoria obtenida con `malloc( )`, **tienes que conservar el puntero que `malloc( )` te devuelve**. Y tu pierdes ese puntero (le asignas otro valor a la variable que lo contiene),

Comment: En ese caso, que seria lo ideal para no quedarme sin memoria o ir la liberando?

Comment: **Conservando** el puntero que te devuelve `malloc( )`, cuando ya no necesites un bloque y quieras *liberarlo*, se usa `free( VALOR_QUE_TE_DEVOLVIÓ_MALLOC )`. En el caso de la lista, cuando ya **no necesites para nada** un nodo, harias el `free( )`.